# jdbc executeBatch hangs when using the combination of MySQL and BoneCP

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, bonecp, autocommit

Here is my code for reading SQL from a file and then do batch updates

```
public void update(Connection conn, File f) {
    Statement st = null;
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        st = conn.createStatement(); 

        //Scann the file line by line and addBatch each line...

        st.executeBatch();
        conn.commit();

        /************************/
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        /************************/

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (st != null) { st.close();}
            if (conn != null) { conn.close(); }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Database I have tried: `HSQLDB(in-process mode)`, `HSQLDB(memory mode)`, `MySQL`

DB Pooling I have tried:`No Pooling(DriverManger)`, `DBCP`, `BoneCP`

My application runs in the following sequence:

```
1. one batchUpdate() to execute many "create table" and "insert" SQL statement
2. many executeQuery() to execute many "select" SQL statement
3. one batchUpdate() to execute many "drop table" statement
```

Almost all combinations of DB and DB Pool works perfectly without the `conn.setAutoCommit(true);` that I highlighted in the code, except for one: `BoneCP`+`MySQL`. For this combination to work, I have to put that `conn.setAutoCommit(true);` at the end of the `update()` code. Other wise, the program would hang at the beginning of the 3rd process(2nd batchUpdate).

My guess was that it hangs because it waits for the `write lock` to be released, and the only possible reason for my 1st `batchUpdate()` to hold the lock may be because I set the connection to not commit automatically and that has caused BoneCP to not release the `write lock`. So I added the `setAutCommit(true)` and it worked. The program doesn't hang anymore.

So, I just want to ask, was my guess right? or is it because of something else? Should it be considered as a bug, since no other combination exerts this kind of odd behavior? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you execute the DDL in a separate transaction?

Comment: you mean to separate the `create` and the `insert` ?

Comment: DDL is `create` and `drop`, try to use those in separate transactions.

Comment: Since I understood insert is part of DML, and create is not, that's why I asked the previous question of `if you mean is to separate the 2`. Please, if you may be of certain of your reasoning of your solution, could elaboration on it may be expected? Much gratitude and appreciation!!!

Comment: Your problem could have to do with having the `create` and `drop` in the same transaction as the `insert`s. I don't know enough about MySQL specifically, that is why I suggest you try it (some database systems don't even allow you to use a table in the same transaction that created it, others will automatically commit if you execute DDL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BoneCP had a bug (fixed in 0.8.0-rc3) whereby autocommit wasn't set to true by default as per spec.

You can set config.setDefaultAutoCommit(true) to get around the issue.